# android studio can not import project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-14.04

I created a new project in Android Studio. I'm using Windows 8 and in another pc I have Ubuntu 14. When I run my project in Ubuntu everything is okay, but now I try to import my project in studio(windows 8), but I can't import project.

> It shows an infinite loader.

I have no idea what is a wrong

p.s

> I also tried reinstalling android studio in windows 8 but nothing changed.

Comment: You used File-->Export (in Ubuntu project)?

Comment: yesterday i imported my project in ubuntu and did some.and today i try to import this project in windows,but i can't @ Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: Is your SDK and Android Studio up to date?

Comment: Since you already got the project on windows machinne, but it is an old version, open the directory (of win project), open the dir (of ubuntu project) and copy-override all files in ubuntu project to win project.
IMPORTANT: before doing it make a backup copy.

I know it's not the best way to import a project but it should work anyway
Hope i helped

Comment: @as i said i reistalling android studio and today i can import another project but i can't import project witch i used in ubuntu

Comment: @ Pier Giorgio Misley i tryed  but nothing changed